# Console application: How to update the display?

Tags: c#, cmd

You have some better options for refresh display of cmd app? If I'm using this method after 6/15 clears cmd close.

I want get this effect: https://i.imgur.com/pAm2dPm.gifv

I have this effect: https://i.imgur.com/UrNqHzs.gifv

```
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Data.CPM = Data.CPS;
                Data.CPS = 0;
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Running XeroxCC!", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - CPM: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)(Data.CPM * 60), Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Checked: [", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.check, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.Write("/", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.total, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.Write("]", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Errors: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.err, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Good: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.hits, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Bad: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.bad, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - 2FA: ", (object)Data.twofas, Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.twofas, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Locked: ", (object)Data.twofas, Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.locked, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Colorful.Console.Clear();
            }
        }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQYRA.gif
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this question...

Try this to reset console status to original.

```
 Console.ResetColor();
```

And, maybe, you need: **`color`** cmd command.

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "/C color";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

See more about RUN cmd commands in c# [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)