# Console application C#: How to refresh the display?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cmd, console

You have some better options for refresh display of cmd app?
If im using this method after 6/15 clears cmd close.
Please help me with this code anyone can help me and fix it??
I want get this effect: https://i.imgur.com/pAm2dPm.gifv
I have this effect: https://i.imgur.com/UrNqHzs.gifv

```
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Data.CPM = Data.CPS;
                Data.CPS = 0;
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Running XeroxCC!", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - CPM: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)(Data.CPM * 60), Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Checked: [", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.check, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.Write("/", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.total, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.Write("]", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Errors: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.err, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Good: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.hits, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Bad: ", Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.bad, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - 2FA: ", (object)Data.twofas, Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.twofas, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Colorful.Console.Write("            - Locked: ", (object)Data.twofas, Color.White);
                Colorful.Console.Write("{0}", (object)Data.locked, Color.MediumPurple);
                Colorful.Console.WriteLine();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Colorful.Console.Clear();
            }
```

Comment: `6/15 clears cmd close` what do you mean? it is more likely that something is finishing your whole app, really. i had apps using `Console.Clear()` run for days with no issues

Comment: You already asked [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685734/console-application-how-to-update-the-display) a few hours ago. Don't create new accounts to post duplicates.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to call `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.ReadKey()` to hold the screen for user input.

Right now, your program does what it is supposed to do & then exits. Once you clear the screen, call any of the above method to hold the screen for you to see.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.Clear();
Console.ReadKey();
```